# Help with extruding handles on vase

Tags: mesh, objects, vertices, extrude

. Hi, I'm having some problems when I'm trying to extrude sides of a vase to create a handle. For one, I tried extruding faces and first inverting then doing a bridge edge loops, so that didn't work out for me because it looked very messy and not the shape I wanted for my object. Second, I tried BlenderGuru's way of extruding like the cup handles in his donut tutorial and that also did not give me good results. I would like to have a rounded handle like shown below. Should I just make a separate mesh then join it to my main mesh? I'm unsure how to progress from here. So now I am quite stuck on how to do this and if anyone could point me in the right direction I really would appreciate it! Photos below. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You do not need that much polygons. Create simple geometry and add a subdivision modifier on top: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdivision_surface If your polycount would be way lower it's pretty straight forward to add any handle you want...

Comment: @brockmann Hi! Yes I definitely have too many, I was doing the shape by path and subdividing to get the details I want. I did just try to make a lower poly version and still am unhappy with how it's turned out. I'm not sure why I just am failing at making these handles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my opinion you should work with much less vertices:

Create your shape:

[image]

Cut a hole, extrude and round with *LoopTools > Circle*:

[image]

[image]

Extrude a bit and tilt the extrusion:

[image]

Symmetrize:

[image]

Select the 2 circles and bridge with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Bridge Edge Loops*, play with the *Operator* box parameters:

[image]

Edit: Your circles are not correctly tilted, you need to slightly rotate them so that they bridge the right way:

[image]

Also don't leave the inner faces:

[image]

Comment: Hi! When you say cut a hole, how exactly would I cut it in the exact middle of the vertices? I still am not the best at cutting shapes but have been using boolean. Your instructions are very clear I appreciate it.

Comment: select one vertex only, delete it, it will create a 8 vertex hole, select these 8 vertices, extrude inwards, then right click > LoopTools > Circle (you need to enable the LoopTools addon)

Comment: Okay thanks for the info about looptools. I think what is catching me is the rotating, the mesh is starting to look very weird (vertices not lined up like how yours are, mine are spiraling) and I guess I will just practice it more to understand how to make the handle. Your instructions and picture explanations are very helpful regardless.

Comment: what do you mean by vertices not lined up?

Comment: Okay nevermind I think I've figured it out by playing around with the rotation settings. So now I have done symmetrize and bridge edge loops, but of course it doesn't look all that great, so how would I 'play with operator box parameters'? I've been going through the different editing settings in the bridge edge loops 'pop-up box' but not getting the handle like how yours is. I apologize if this is easy information, I'm still learning bit by bit.

Comment: it's a bit hard to say without seeing what you've done  ;)  remember to tilt the 2 circles a bit before doing the bridge, then you can control the parameters like the curve shape with the Smoothness value and the Number of Cuts

Comment: Hi, right sure, I have a ss for you here if you have the time to check it for me (https://i.imgur.com/juoKUxc.png). Yes I did tilt them a bit and with the symmetrize but I'm just stuck on how to make it curve upwards? What I'm seeing is that it is curving inside of the mesh so I don't know how to make it curve the other way (ss here: https://i.imgur.com/Rw8bLob.png)? I understand now what you mean about the smoothness value and cuts. Very confused by it's going inside and not out.

Comment: could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hi, sure, here: https://pasteall.org/blend/04c25daf2ff54ff48a67018c32ab3acc

Comment: I've edited my answer, I hope it's clear, the bridge will look for the shortest way between the selections